# How to show certain options from a combobox only when another option is selected with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, combobox

I searched around a bit, but couldn't find an answer that would work for me.

Let's say i have a combobox with 5 options, like so:

```
           <tr>
                <td>
                        <SELECT class=caixas id=cbostatus style="WIDTH: 3cm;" tabIndex=25 name=cbostatus onchange= "StatusTest();"> 
                            <option selected></option>
                            <option value="Planned" <?php if ($row['task_status']=='Planned') echo 'selected="selected"';?> style='display:none;'>Planned</option>
                            <option value="Started"<?php if ($row['task_status']=='Started') echo 'selected="selected"';?>style='display:none;'>Started</option>
                            <option value="Available"<?php if ($row['task_status']=='Available') echo 'selected="selected"';?>style='display:none;'>Available</option>
                            <option value="Finished"<?php if ($row['task_status']=='Finished') echo 'selected="selected"';?>style='display:none;'>Finished</option>
                            <option value="Impeded"<?php if ($row['task_status']=='Impeded') echo 'selected="selected"';?>style='display:none;'>Impeded</option>
                        </SELECT>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

When i open the page, it already loads a pre-selected option. For testing purposes, i'm opening the "Planned" option. But when the "Planned" option is selected, i  want to show only the "Planned" option, and the "Started" option.

My logic was to make all of the options invisible, then make a javascript function OnLoad, and it looked like this:

```
    function ComboChoose(){
        if (document.getElementById('cbostatus').value == "Planned"){
        form.cbostatus.options[form.cbostatus.selectedIndex].value["Started"].style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```

Basically, i think this is a problem with not knowing the right syntax to use in a situation like this, so if someone could point me in the right direction, i'd be very thankful!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to try using a dynamically-assembled option using some `data` values. You can populate the data fields dynamically using PHP's `json_encode(array());` if need be. See if this option is something you are interested in:

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/a3tuj7yu/

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<select class="caixas" id="cbostatus" style="WIDTH: 3cm;" tabIndex="25" name="cbostatus"
    data-getpairs='{"":["Planned","Started","Available","Finished","Impeded"],"Planned":["Started"],"Started":["Available","Impeded"]}'
    data-getselected='<?php echo $row['task_status']; ?>'
>
</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    function dynamicOpts(obj,sPairs,sSelected)
        {
            obj.html('');
            var sOptions    =   ["<option value=''>Select</option>"];
            if(sSelected != '')
                sOptions.push("<option value='"+sSelected+"' selected='selected'>"+sSelected+"</option>");

            $.each(sPairs,function(k,v){
                if(sSelected == k) {
                    $.each(v,function(sk,sv){
                        sOptions.push("<option value='"+sv+"'>"+sv+"</option>");
                    });
                }
            });

            obj.append(sOptions.join(''));
        }

    var selectMenu  =   $("#cbostatus");
    var sValue      =   selectMenu.val();
    var sPairs      =   selectMenu.data('getpairs');
    var sSelected   =   selectMenu.data('getselected');

 dynamicOpts(selectMenu,sPairs,sSelected);

    $(this).on('change',"#cbostatus",function(){
        sSelected   =   $(this).val();
        dynamicOpts($(this),sPairs,sSelected);
    });
});
</script>
```